# C++: Comparing individual elements of a string to their ASCII values?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, comparison, ascii

I am trying to write a small program that determines if a string is a palindrome. Naturally, I want to ignore any character that is not a letter. I planned on achieving this by checking each element of the string by comparing their ASCII values to values that I determined: [65,90] U [97,122]

The following code is a segment from a function in which a string, `string aStrn`, is passed in.

```
while(aStrn[index] != '\0')
{
    if(aStrn[index] > 64 && aStrn[index] < 91 && aStrn[index] > 96 &&
       aStrn[index] < 123)
    {
        ordered.Push(aStrn[index]);
    }
    index++;
}
```

I tested this code by explicitly defining parameters such that `if(aStrn[index] != ' ' && aStrn[index] != '\''...` etc., and it worked perfectly. However, when I try the method shown above, `ordered` remains empty.

I can't for the life of me figure out why, so all help is greatly appreciated. I also understand that there is probably a better way to go about this but I would still like to understand why this does not work.

Comment: How can something be less than 91 and greater than 96 at the same time?

Comment: ... Whoops. `||` incoming...

Comment: Please refrain from using ASCII values.  Use character literals instead, like `'A'`.  Character literals make your code easier to read.  Otherwise, some people may have to try and find an ASCII chart to read your code (I haven't memorized the *decimal* values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing parentheses and 'OR' operator. Simple mistake.

`if((aStrn[index] > 64 && aStrn[index] < 91) || (aStrn[index] > 96 && aStrn[index] < 123))` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, you want to put your strings into `std::string` objects, use `std::isalpha` to determine whether something is a letter, and probably `std::copy_if` to copy the qualifying data from the source to the destination.

```
std::string source = "This is 1 non-palindromic string!";
std::string dest;

std::copy_if(source.begin(), source.end(),
             std::back_inserter(dest),
             [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); });
```

You might also want to convert the string entirely to lower (or upper) case to make comparisons easier (assuming you want to treat upper and lower case letters as equal). That's also pretty trivial:

```
std::transform(dest.begin(), dest.end(), 
               dest.begin(),
               [](unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); });
```

Answer (score 0):

you're allowed to compare against character literals.

```
if (aStrn[index] >= 'a' && aStrn[index] <= 'z' /* ... */) // for example
```

But there are [standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) functions that do the work for you.

```
if (std::isalpha(aStrn[index])) {
    //...
}
```